# Cocoa - changing spaces spontaneously

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I wrote a project that is working as a background app and I have this little issue.

Let's say I have 3 open desktops (spaces) on my mac:

1. Space with open NSWindow from my project
2. Empty space with no open folder apps
3. Space with for example open folder

I am currently on space number 1.

I swipe 3 fingers left to switch to en empty space, and then again, to switch to a space with open folder (which immediately gets focus).

Then I swipe 3 fingers right to switch from 3rd space to 2nd, and what happens is that it (IMO) knows, that there is not a single NSWindow there to be focused on, so it switches to 1st space (without me even touching the touchpad) and NSWindow from my app is focused now.

My question is - **how to prevent this?** I mean, I don't remember setting such thing on purpose (my app is based on getting current focused NSWindow, but only when user clicks on a window).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your app is considered still active when you first switch to space 2. Then, when you switch back from space 3 to 2, your app is reactivated (since it was the last active on that space), which makes your app's window the main/key window, and the default behavior is to switch to the window's space when it becomes main/key.

You can change the system behavior with System Preferences > Mission Control > When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application.

You can change your app's behavior by setting the window's `collectionBehavior` property to include `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace`, although that would result in your app's window moving to space 2. This can also be set in IB using the Attributes inspector.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but is there a way to programmatically prevent this from happening without moving my app window to active space? I find this pretty weird, as other apps do not behave the same.

Comment: Is it in fact that case that when you first switch to space 2, your app is still active? You can tell by the menu bar. Also, can you reproduce this with a new, simple Cocoa project? If a new project doesn't reproduce it, then you need to examine what you did with yours that makes it different.